# How to add HTML formatting to javascript string

Tags: javascript, html

I need to add some HTML formatting to a javascript string presented to me by amCharts for a graph I am on.

The first part of the code below is all correct and brings in the data I need, the second part of the code links the data to the actual title within the chart.

The question is how would I add the HTML attribute 
 to the string in the second part
so that the date pulled will fall under the first part of the heading.

FIRST PART

```
chart1.addListener("rendered",function(e) {
e.chart.periodSelector.addListener("changed",function() {
var date = $(".amChartsPeriodSelector .amChartsInputField").map(function() {
return $(this).val(); }).get();
$(this).html(date.join(' <i style="color: #F47C00;">to</i> '));
```

SECOND PART

```
    chart1.panels[0].titles[0].text = "VPM Global Select Opportunities Unit Price - US     Dollars:  " + html('<br>') + date; //name of variable in PT 1
    chart1.panels[0].validateData();
 });
});
```

You help is much appreciated.

need header to look like this:

VPM Global Select Opportunities Unit Price - US Dollars

2014-02-03 to 2014-03-03

Comment: What is being displayed in your case? &lt;br&gt; ?

Comment: nothing currently, what I would like to add is a <br> tag before the. text and bring in the concantineted join mentioned in the first part

Comment: I don't know how chart1.panels[0].titles[0].text is used further. Can't you just test like `chart1.panels[0].titles[0].text = "VPM...";` `chart1.panels[0].titles[0].text = chart1.panels[0].titles[0].text + '<br>'`; etc. ?

Direct assignment works for me like `$("#id").html('VPM' + '<br>' +  ...);`